# ZeroClipBoard - copy text to clipboard

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, zeroclipboard

I want to copy string into clipboard on a function call or page load. Please see below code

```
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

        <div id="d_clip_button" style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

        <script language="JavaScript">
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            var myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";
            clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
            clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy text on button click is working fine. But i dont have any button in my project .I want to copy text inside a JS function. Please help me.

Thanks in advance
Manu v nath

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible, because java script can not fire Flash events due security risk.